# Inverted search in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, inverted-index

I'm trying to implement an inverted search as part of map reduce, first part of which I was able to complete (mapper). The output of first part looks something like below
(headings are for reference, these are not in actual output of mapper)

```
word     frequency     document
------------------------------
tire        1           car
headlight   1           shop
tire        1           car
gas         1           gasstation
beer        1           gasstation
headlight   1           car
tire        1           shop
```

I'm trying to get to below solution:

The word is found in which file, along with its frequency. (for example tire is found twice in car file)

Until now I have tried using dictionary to get the files in which the word is found, but I am unable to link it to get count, below is the output I'm getting:

```
{'car':[tire,tire,headlight],'shop':[headlight],'gasstation':[gas,beer]}
```

Expected:

```
tire           {'car':2,'shop':1}
headlight      {'car':1, 'shop':1}
```

Comment: Please note that "expected" is not a placeholder for the *desired* output. Why did you expect that output? Where's the code you expected to produce it? Give a [mcve].

Comment: Look at Counter class

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce) the dict you have to group the elements in your list.

Assuming the output of your mapping is a list of dicts like this:

```
mapped_data = [
    { 'word': 'tire', 'frequency': 1, 'document': 'car' },
    { 'word': 'headlight', 'frequency': 1, 'document': 'shop' }
]
```

Then you could do something like:

```
def reducer(accumulated, line):
    # We've never seen this word before, create the dict to store the documents
    if line['word'] not in accumulated:
        accumulated[line['word']] = {}

    # We've never seen this word in this document before, initialize the counter.
    if line['document'] not in accumulated[line['word']]:
        accumulated[line['word']][line['document']] = 0

    # Increment th counter
    accumulated[line['word']][line['document']] += line['frequency']

    return accumulated_data

reduce(reducer, mapped_data, {})
```

This would produce the expected result:

```
{
    'tire': {
        'car': 2,
        'shop': 1
    },
    'headlight': {
        ...
    },
    ...
}
```